# Laravel 5.1 eloquent Unsupported operand types

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am trying to get query result to array and show them in select element. When I hardcode it like this, it works fine:

```
$categories = ['Editorial', 'Product test', 'News', 'Feature'];
$categories = ['select_category']+$categories;  

return view('admin.articles.create', compact('categories'));
```

But when I try to get categories form DB, I get the above mentioned error.

```
$categories = Category::all();
$categories = ['select_category']+$categories;

return view('admin.articles.create', compact('categories'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Category::all();` will return a collection and not an array.

You should be able to get around this by using `toArray()` e.g.

```
$categories = Category::all()->toArray();
```

Hope this helps!